# How to display the assigned property component in QML QT5?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

In Main.qml

```
Item {
    id:windowId
    width:200;height;200;
    Page{
      style: MyStyle{
           id:myStyleId
           background: Rectangle{
                width:30;height;30;color:"blue"
           }  
           background2: Rectangle{
                width:10;height;10;color:"green"
           }             
      }
    }
}
```

In Page.qml

```
Item {
    id: pageId
    property MyStyle style
    //How to display the style property
}
```

In MyStyle.qml

```
 Item {
    id: mystyleId
    property Rectangle background
    property Rectangle background2
    //How to display the background and background2 properties
 }
```

As you can see above I have style property assigned with MyStyle while creating Page

How do I display the style property inside Page and background property insode MyStyle.

I have tried doing like this in Page.qml and also similarly in MyStyle.qml, but still it is not displaying without any errors

```
Item {
    property alias style : loader.sourceComponent

    Loader { id: loader }
}
```

A rough drawing at the end: (1) Page.qml; (2,3) Rectangles from Style.qml

[image: Main]

Comment: Could you add a small drwaing illustrating your desired result, and choose one of the Qt versions - either Qt4 or Qt5. Things might differ dramatically in those versions. I can only help with Qt5

Comment: @derM I have made a rough sketch and it is for Qt5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items that are assigned to a property won't get their `parent` set.

When you have the notion:

```
ItemA {
    ItemB {}
}
```

`ItemB` will be automatically set to be part of `ItemA.children` and `ItemB.parent` will be set to `ItemA`.

This does not happen, if you write:

```
ItemA {
    property Item someItem: ItemB {}
}
```

Here you leave `ItemB.parent` to be `null`, and `ItemB` won't appear in `ItemA.children`.

---

This means, you need to set this manually, by either adding it to the desired parents `children`-property, or by setting the `parent`-property of the child.

```
ItemA {
    id: itmA
    property Item someItem: ItemB { parent: itmA }
}
```

makes `ItemB` to appear.

---

As, most likely, you don't want to write that everytime you put something in that property you can use the `onPropertyChanged`-slot to do this:

```
ItemA {
    property Item someItem
    onSomeItemChanged: someItem.parent = this
}
```

In this case, when you assign a new `Item` to `someItem` the former one won't lose the parent however, and will still be drawn at the same position. So you might also want to create a connection to remove the parent again.
For this we will create a closure to store the reference for the connection:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property Item someItem
    onSomeItemChanged: {
        console.log('SomeItem changed')
        someItem.parent = root
        this.onSomeItemChanged.connect(generateClosure(someItem))
    }

    function generateClosure(smeItm) {
        return function() { if (someItem !== smeItm) { smeItm.parent = null } }
    }
}
```

or if you want to *restore the original parent* we use this function for the closure:

```
function generateClosure(smeItm, originalParent) {
    return function() { if (someItem !== smeItm) { smeItm.parent = originalParent } }
}
```

and make sure, we call it as long as we still have a reference to the original parent.